# In SQL, is it a syntax error to appoint a different datatype to a Foreign Key than to the Primary Key it references?

Tags: sql, types, syntax, key, semantics

I've gotten into an argument with my professor about this question, so please give me your input.

The original question was:

Is there a syntax error in this script?

```
CREATE TABLE Dozent
   ( DozNr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      Name VARCHAR(30));

CREATE TABLE Prüfung
   ( DozentNr CHAR(3), StudentNr CHAR(6),
     PRIMARY KEY (DozentNr, StudentNr),
     FOREIGN KEY (DozentNr) REFERENCES Dozent(DozNr),
     FOREIGN KEY (StudentNr) REFERENCES Student(MatrNr) );
```

So obviously there's a mistake because the Foreign Key DozentNr is declared as a CHAR, while the Primary Key it references is of INTEGER datatype.
My first impulse was to say that it's a semantic error to appoint something the wrong datatype. My professor said that it was a syntax error though (without any explanation of course).

Some research brought me these definitions:

> Rules of syntax specify how language elements are sequenced to form
> valid statements. Thus, syntactic checking verifies that keywords,
> object names, operators, delimiters, and so on are placed correctly in
> your SQL statement.

> Rules of semantics specify how valid external references are made. Thus,
> semantic checking verifies that references to database objects and host
> variables are valid and that host variable datatypes are correct.

Source:
[Oracle9i Database Online Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_adchk.htm)

When I sent my professor this, she just said:
"The use of a wrong datatype is a syntax error. The reference was defined but the datatype didn't match."

This is hardly an explanation to me but after asking her twice I didn't want to ask her the same  question again.
If you know the answer, please explain.

Comment: "The garden rode a horse" is grammatically (syntactically) correct. The fact it doesn't make sense has nothing to do with grammar (syntax). The same applies here, I think.

Comment: Some people use words wrong. For some, any compilation error they see is a "syntax error" no matter whether the error message actually reports a syntax error or not. Apparently your professor is one of these people. This is unfortunate. They may also be the type of person who will not accept feedback indicating that they're incorrect, so you may have to just accept that you'll have to use words wrong too when communicating with them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really agree with either of you -- although I don't think the distinction is important.

I am guessing that your professor is dividing errors into a handful of categories, such as:

- syntax errors
- execution errors
- security access errors

And that "semantic error" is not on the list.  The use of "syntax error" in this context probably really means "error during the compilation phase" rather than "error during the execution phase".

"Semantics" refers to meaning, so I would think of `on s.student_id = h.hospital_id` as a *semantic* error, because although the two ids are integers (for this example ;), they are not really appropriate as a `join` condition.

I'm not sure that this error is an error of *meaning*.  It is a type incompatibility error.  Why not just call this error a foreign key definition error?  Or a compile-time error?